# SQL percentage not reaching 100%

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

Hello sorry for bad english or anything.

I have a little problem in my SQL query if i had table like this

```
item amount itemtype sumamount percentage
1     100       1      300        0,33
2     100       2      300        0,33
3     100       3      300        0,33
```

```
with s as (
select itemtype, sum(amount) as sum
from test3
group by itemtype)

x as (
select s.*, amount/sum as persen from test3 t inner join s on t.itemtype = s.itemtype)
select sum(persen) from x
```

and I'm looking for the sum of the percentage it doesn't end up as 100% how to solve this ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we start from here:

```
with s as ( select itemtype, sum(amount) as sum_c
            from test3
           group by itemtype),
x as ( select s.*, amount/sum_c as persen 
       from test3 t 
       inner join s on t.itemtype = s.itemtype)
select sum(persen) from x;
```

Please never use keywords as aliases(example : sum)

This returns number 3 from your example and your question is: "SQL percentage not reaching 100%". So it is not realy clear what you want to acomplishe here...

Your first query will retun :

> ```
> itemtype  sum_c
>        1  100
>        2  100
>        3  100
> ```

Which is logical when you group by itemtype.

In your second query you are deviding that result of `sum_c` with the amount which is 100/100 and the result is:

> ```
> itemtype  sum_c   persen
>        1    100        1
>        2    100        1
>        3    100        1
> ```

So, pleaase update your question with the result you want to get from this example data.

Here is a demo of your example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd6244948053822b1f339d7939ef7723
Maybe it will help you or maybe others to give you a solution...

Comment: so this is an example of the items that i had so how can I sum those 3 items with 0.33 percentage can be 100% ? because in my query it always endup with 0.99999999999

Comment: Hi, you want to sum this 3 items you have given as example?

Comment: Hi @AdzieFatharoni, Well you can do it simple as this: `select ceiling(sum(percentage)) *100 from test3;` but I am not sure if this is what you need ? If it is I will update my answer...

Comment: well actually there's no percentage column, there's only item, itemtype, amount.

Comment: Show me the query that you use when you get 0,99

Comment: ```with s as (
select itemtype, sum(amount) as sum
from test3
group by itemtype),
x as (
select s.*, amount/sum as persen from test3 t inner join s on t.itemtype = s.itemtype)
select sum(persen) from x ```

Comment: Hi @AdzieFatharoni , do you see the link at the bottom of my answer ? As I have explained this query will return 3 and not 0,99 so please give me the query that gives you the 0,99... If you have some other example data than the ones you have shown us then try: `with s as ( select itemtype, sum(amount) as sum 
from test3 group by itemtype), 
x as ( select s.*, amount/sum as persen from test3 t 
inner join s on t.itemtype = s.itemtype) 
select ceiling(sum(persen)) from x;`

Comment: Hi @AdzieFatharoni and ?

Comment: i was wondering how can u come up with 3 as the result in fact i was wrong, the itemtype is all 1 not 1,2,3. thanks mate

Comment: it actually worked like the round function I used before, but in this case I want the calculation in the x one, in the end if I want to sum up the 'persen' it's perfectly 1, for example one of those 0.33 can be transformed into 0.34. thanks

Comment: Hi @AdzieFatharoni , I am sorry I do not understand. So this answer is not correct. You want to round one number before the total number ?

Comment: Hi @AdzieFatharoni  I believe that in that case this is another question. I have shown you: 1. where is your question example asked wrong (the data) and I ask you to correct it please in your question. Just clikc edit under the question and change the example data... 2. I have explained why the final result is not 100 and that you actualy are geting 0,99 and want 1 for result and not 100. So I suggest to you to open a new question where you will explian your problem in a better way and with some exact examples of what you ned and want.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dividing 2 numbers they might not round up to the exact number.
For example 1/3 is 0.33333333... until the end of time, but this can not be stored in a computer system so we need to round them down somewhere.
You can increase the precision of the calculation by casting the sum to a different number type for example real.

```
with s as (
select itemtype, sum(amount) as sum
from test3
group by itemtype)

x as (
select s.*, CAST(amount as real)/sum as persen from test3 t inner join s on t.itemtype = s.itemtype)
select sum(persen) from x
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to keep more decimal points and not worry about the difference.  Your query appears to be written more simply as:

```
select t3.*,
       amount * 1.0 / sum(amount) over (partition by itemtype) as ratio
from test3 t3;
```

This should return results like 0.3333333.  If you really want one value to be slightly off to make the sum 100%.  Then you can do some manipulation and arithmetic:

```
select t3.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by itemtype order by item) = 1
             then (sum(ratio) over (partition by itemtype order by item) - ratio)
             else ratio
        end) as ratio
from (select t3.*,
             convert(decimal(10, 4), amount * 1.0 / sum(amount) over (partition by itemtype)) as ratio
      from test3 t3
     ) t3;
```

The extra arithmetic ensures that the value adds up to 1.